# How to pass values to a function with pointer

Tags: java, c

I am new To C programming language. I have created a header file in java so that I can call C function from java. My problem is I don't know how to pass values to the method here is my C code.

```
_declspec(dllimport) HANDLE FAR PASCAL CPSC1900Connect(BYTE port, void *param);

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_CPSE_CPSC1900Connect(JNIEnv * env, jclass hPrinter, jstring port, jstring param)
{
     HANDLE hMapFile = NULL;
     const char *str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, port, 0);
     const char *str2 = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, param, 0);
     hMapFile = CPSC1900Connect((BYTE )str,&str2);
     (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, port, str);
     (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, param, str2);

     return param;
}
```

I need to call `CPSC1900Connect(BYTE port, void *param)` function and pass port and param respectively . How do I pass these values. Any correction from the above code is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide the other files or snippets of the other files?

Comment: maybe having the `port` parameter as `jbyte` or `jint` could help

Comment: What do you want `param` to be? A pointer to what?

Comment: @iharob CPSC1900Connect(BYTE port, void *param); tha is the method I need to call. BYTE rc = CPSC1900Connect(PORT , IPADDRESS); from java am passing port and ipaddress but I don't know how to pass that C function kindly assist am stuck

Comment: and this is my native java method. You can correct me if there is any error  public  native byte CPSC1900Connect(String port,String param);

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is calling another C function that will return the pointer value that you want and then you can pass that return value into other functions as needed. At the end of the day pointers (memory addresses) are just numbers so Java will be able to store it and use it in future JNI calls.